# What should I do if I denied my wifi company to do a hard inquiry ( credit check) but they did It anyway?

Tags: united-states, new-jersey

I did not gave them my social and unchecked the option where it said uncheck the box if you don't want us to do a credit check. I confirmed with them on chat and on phone that they wont do it. Just 15 mins after submitting the order I get a mail from credit karma saying the wifi company did a hard inquiry on my credit report.

Comment: Was there any damage to you done by the check or you just don't want them doing it for your own personal reasons you don't want to go into?   Not that it matters all that much, as it sounds like a civil tort and nothing criminal on their part.  The damages might change the nature of how you want to go about it.

Comment: Are you sure it was "hard". I work for a loan company, and we can't do a hard check without a SSN, but we can do a soft one with just your name and 1 other identifier, such as address or phone number.